# Show that f has a minimun

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, extreme-value-theorem

been trying to solve this for some time now.

> f is continuous in $ [0,\infty), $ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = L . $
>   prove that if there exist $x \ge 0 $ such that f(x) < L then f has a minimum in $ [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Are you trying to show that $f$ has a local minimum or a global minimum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists some $y\in[0,\infty)$ such that $f(t)>f(x)$ for $t\ge y$. Then $f$ meets a minimum in $[0,y]$.

Comment: @anderstood Thank you, I have remade my answer.